# Split String without removing separator in Elixir?

Tags: regex, string, split, elixir

I'm looking for a way to split a string in Elixir without removing the pattern used to split, [`String.split/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#split/3) behaves like this

```
String.split "testZng", "Z"
# ["test", "ng"]
```

I'm looking for something like this

```
String.split "testZng", "Z"
# ["test", "Zng"]
```

Or like this

```
String.split "testZng", "Z"
# ["testZ", "ng"]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use [**lookarounds**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
Regex.split ~r/(?=Z)/, "testZng"
# ["test", "Zng"]

Regex.split ~r/(?<=Z)/, "testZng"
# ["testZ", "ng"]
```

The `(?=Z)` is a positive lookahead that matches a location in the string that is immediately followed with a `Z` char.

The `(?<=Z)` is a positive lookbehind that matches a location in the string that is immediately preceded with `Z`.

Answer (score 0):

Another potential approach:

```
defmodule StackOverflow do
  def split(string, <<split_char_cp>> = split_char, split_pos \\ :split_after) do
    if String.contains?(string, split_char) do
      index = string |> to_charlist |> Enum.find_index(&(split_char_cp == &1))
      String.split_at(string, if(split_pos == :split_after, do: index + 1, else: index))
    else
      ""
    end
  end
end
# Used like this: 
# import StackOverflow
# split("TestZng","Z")  
# => {"TestZ","ng"}
# split("TestZng","Z",:split_before)
# => {"Test","Zng"}
# split("TestZng","h")
# => ""
```

I'm not sure if this is any better or worse than the RegEx lookarounds. I just offer it for sake of completeness.